# Scatterplot without any values in both variables or in one of them

Tags: r

As the title says, I want to see the empty plot with the coordinate system and the axis even if there are no values available.

So far I get an error for those smoothScatter-functions, that do not contain values.

```
    a1 <- subset(a, datasource == 1)
    a2 <- subset(a, datasource == 2)
    a3 <- subset(a, datasource == 3)
    a4 <- subset(a, datasource == 4)
    a5 <- subset(a, datasource == 5)
    a6 <- subset(a, datasource == 6)
    a7 <- subset(a, datasource == 7)
    par(mfrow=c(3,3))
    smoothScatter(a$profiledepth, a$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
    smoothScatter(a1$profiledepth, a1$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
    smoothScatter(a2$profiledepth, a2$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
    smoothScatter(a3$profiledepth, a3$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
    smoothScatter(a4$profiledepth, a4$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
    smoothScatter(a5$profiledepth, a5$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
    smoothScatter(a6$profiledepth, a6$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
    smoothScatter(a7$profiledepth, a7$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following code. It is large. You can reduce it using loop.

```
    a1 <- subset(a, datasource == 1)
a2 <- subset(a, datasource == 2)
a3 <- subset(a, datasource == 3)
a4 <- subset(a, datasource == 4)
a5 <- subset(a, datasource == 5)
a6 <- subset(a, datasource == 6)
a7 <- subset(a, datasource == 7)
par(mfrow=c(3,3))

if(length(a)!=0){
smoothScatter(a$profiledepth, a$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}

if(length(a1)!=0){
smoothScatter(a1$profiledepth, a1$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}

if(length(a2)!=0){
smoothScatter(a2$profiledepth, a2$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}


if(length(a3)!=0){
smoothScatter(a3$profiledepth, a3$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}


if(length(a4)!=0){
smoothScatter(a4$profiledepth, a4$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}

if(length(a5)!=0){
smoothScatter(a5$profiledepth, a5$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}

if(length(a6)!=0){
smoothScatter(a6$profiledepth, a6$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}

if(length(a7)!=0){
smoothScatter(a7$profiledepth, a4$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
} else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it could solve my problem, but the if statement was not entirely correct:

`if(all(is.na(a$profiledepth))== FALSE & all(is.na(a$horizondepth_lower))== FALSE )
{
smoothScatter(a$profiledepth, a$horizondepth_lower, nbin=256, nrpoints=0, ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}
else {
plot(x=1:52,y=1:52,type="n",ylim=c(0,520), xlim=c(0,520), main='Alle', ylab='Tiefe der Horizontuntergrenze / cm', xlab='Profiltiefe / cm')
}`